# Share multi images with caption on Facebook using Intent in Android

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-intent

I want to share multi images with caption on Facebook using Intent. I tried some ways but it doesn't work. I can share photos but not the caption. Can you help me, please? Thanks!!!

My share function

```
private void share(String nameApp, ArrayList<String> imagePath, String text) {
        try {
            List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
            Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            share.setType("image/*");
            List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
            if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
                for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
                    Intent targetedShare = new Intent(
                            android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
                    targetedShare.setType("image/*"); 
                    if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(nameApp)           
                            || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(nameApp)) {
                        ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < nImageCount; i++){
                            uris.add(Uri.parse("file://" + imagePath.get(i)));
                        }
                        targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, text);
                        targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
                        targetedShare.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
                        targetedShare.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                        targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShare);
                    }
                }
                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(
                        targetedShareIntents.remove(0), "Select app to share");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                        targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[] {}));
                startActivity(chooserIntent);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain, **completely and precisely**, what "it doesn't work" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I updated my question above

Answer (score 0):

First, you are not using `EXTRA_SUBJECT`, which is where I would expect a "caption" to go.

Second, there is no `EXTRA_TITLE` in the documentation for `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`.

Third, there is no requirement for any app to necessarily honor `EXTRA_SUBJECT` for `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`.

Comment: I want to post on Facebook

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from Facebook developers. They don't support it anymore because of their policy.

They say **"This issue is going to be closed by design because our API does not support pre-filling the message for users as seen in our Policy Documentation here (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/application_integration_points/) under Platform Policy IV.2"**

> https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/332619626816423/